# How to limit the entries using ForeignKey

Tags: django

I have 2 models: in myapp/Models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    foo_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})


class Fighter(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo,limit_choices_to={'foo_admin': currentuser})
```

Is there a way to get the 'currentuser' or (username) and limit the choices in ForeignKey?
i.e Fighter will display foo only if the 'currentuser' is equal to the foo_admin saved in Foo.

Comment: Limit how? To certain number?

Comment: Limit the choise to one user (i.e current user). Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do such things in Model. You will need in views custom filters, something like this `.filter(foo__foo_admin = reguest.user)`. And it's more harder to do in administration interface, because you will need to retrieve current user through method like this:

```
class Example(admin.ModelAdmin):

 def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(Example, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.current_user = request.user
    return form
```